# Ruby prog won't run as LaunchDaemon

Tags: ruby, macos, plist

I have a ruby program, pretty simple, just does DNS lookup on a bunch of hosts. The program runs fine from the terminal (Mac OS X 10.6.5), Ruby 1.9.2 using RVM.

I would like to run this on a schedule and would like to load a LaunchDaemon to do so. The program does not run as a LauanchDaemon, and the output files are created, but empty, so I am unable to see the error(s). I suspect it has something to do with the includes.

Here is the plist (it loads fine and attempts to run as evidenced by the creation of both output files):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.jsw.ping</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Debug</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/var/jsw/logs/ping.txt</string>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
        <dict>
            <key>PATH</key>
                <string>/Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin:/Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/bin:/Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin:/Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/bin:/Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/bin:/Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin:/Users/scott/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/maven/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin</string>
        </dict>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/var/jsw/logs/ping.err.txt</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>ping.rb</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
      <integer>1800</integer>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
        <string>/Library/WebServer/vHosts/scripts/ping/</string>
   <key>UserName</key>
       <string>scott</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

The Ruby program is:

```
#!/Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'  
require 'active_record'
require 'yaml'  
require 'dnsruby'
include Dnsruby


dbconfig = YAML::load(File.open('database.yml'))
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(dbconfig)

# flush cache
rslt = `dscacheutil -flushcache`

Dnsruby::DNS.open 
rslvr = Dnsruby::DNS.new

now = DateTime.now.to_s
mysqlDT = now.gsub("T", " ")
puts mysqlDT


class Host < ActiveRecord::Base  
end  
class Ip < ActiveRecord::Base  
end  

Host.find_each do |svr|
  ip = rslvr.getaddress(svr.host).to_s
  svr.lastIP = ip
  svr.save
  Ip.create(:ip => ip, :host => svr.host, :DT => mysqlDT, :hostID => svr.id)
end
```

Comment: Have you added some kind of logging? It might be helpful to see what is going on inside the script while it is being run by the LaunchDaemon.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add logging. That's what the Std Out Path and Std Err path are supposed to do, but for some reason the files are empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root problem was that the LaunchDaemon job was being run from a shell that did not set up RVM properly and thus the included classes could not be located. Since I don't have any legacy Ruby programs on my system, I removed RVM and installed Ruby 1.9.2 in /usr/local/bin on my system and then re-installed gems.

The second problem (no logging) was due to a permissions error.